# destroy() or close() actually doesn't destroy the object? (Ext-JS 4.1.1a)

Tags: javascript, extjs

Here is my window and form inside of it:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Users.Update', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    title: 'User',
    width: 250,
    id: 'UpdateWindowUsers',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'UpdateFormUsers'
    }],
    buttons: [
      { text: 'Save', id: 'submitUpdateFormButtonUsers'},
      { text: 'Cancel', id: 'cancelUpdateFormButtonUsers'},
    ]
});

Ext.define('App.view.Users.UpdateForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.UpdateFormUsers',
    layout: 'form',
    id: 'UpdateFormUsers',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Id',
        name: 'id',
        hidden: true
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'username',
        name: 'username',
        allowBlank: false,
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'password',
        name: 'password',
        minLength : 5,
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Email',
        name: 'email',
        minLength : 5,
        vtype: 'email',
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'first name',
        name: 'first_name',
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'last name',
        name: 'last_name',
        allowBlank: false
    }],
});
```

It's in one file: "**App/view/Users/Update.js**".

So, I'm creating an object with:

```
var win = Ext.create('App.view.Users.Update');
```

It's created with a button. But when I close the window with `win.close()` and when I close the "tab" inside my "border" layout and when I press the button for creating the same window again, it says (**in my console**) that I'm recreating an object with the same "id" again. It's already registered in Ext.AbstractManager.

How can I fully destroy the object? Maybe with **Ext.AbstractManager.unregister(win);** something?

If you need more code, no problem. :) Thank you.

P. S.

I'm getting a reference to my window with:

```
var window = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#UpdateWindowUsers')[0];
window.close();
```

**Does window.close() actually destroys the panel inside of it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

**this == Controller**

```
if(this.isCreated){
    this.control(listeners);
}
```

I've put `isCreated` property inside Controller.